# Allow the user to input the list position of the word to RETURN to 2nd and 3rd element from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates, nested-lists, python-3.3

I need someone to help me code this WITHOUT using external libraries panda imports exceptions counters

```
lineList = [['Cat', 'c', 1, x],['Cat', 'a', 2, x],['Cat', 't', 3, x],['Bat', 'b', 1, 3],['Bat', 'b', 1, 2],['Mat', 'm', 1, 1],['Fat', 'f', 1, 13]]
```

Words from 2D list that appear more than 2 times are displayed in a numerical list

Eg:

```
1. Cat
2. Bat
```

How can I allow the user to select a word by inputting the **list position number**? So for example if the user enters 1 it will return the second and third elements for Cat in the nested list:

```
c = 1, a = 2, t = 3
```

I am a beginner to Python so not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate), and a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
word_counts = [['Cat', 2], ['Bat', 3], ['Fat', 1], ['Mat', 1]]

filtered = [p for p in word_counts if p[1] > 1]

print('\n'.join('{0}. {1}'.format(i, p[0]) for i, p in enumerate(filtered, 1)))
```

Output:

```
1. Cat
2. Bat
```

For a string in a specific position:

```
n = int(input('position: '))   #   1-indexed

print('{0}. {1}'.format(n, filtered[n - 1][0]))   #   0-indexed (hence, n - 1)
```

Comment: How can i allow the user to select a word by inputting the list position number so eg if they enter 1 it will return Cat with its corresponding values in the nested list eg , 'c', 1, 2 ? :)

Comment: @gstar I just updated my answer with a solution to this problem.

Comment: @gstar You must define it as it is in the first code in my answer, `filtered = [p for p in word_counts if p[1] > 1]`.

Comment: Amazing it worked! The only thing is when I enter 1 it only returns cat. Is there a way to get it to return all the other elements such as c, 1 and 2 as well from LineList eg ['Cat', 'c', 1, 2]

Comment: @gstar What result exactly do you expect if the user inputs `1`?

Comment: [['Cat', 'c', 1, x],['Cat', 'a', 2, x],['Cat', 't', 3, x] = I have updated the list to make it easier to explain ... if the user inputs 1 i expect to get the 2nd and 3rd element from the cat lists so c = 1, a=2 and t=3 if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the words and then use `enumerate` to make the numbers for your list:

```
from collections import Counter

lineList = [['Cat', 'c', 1, 2],['Cat', 'c', 1, 3],['Bat', 'b', 1, 4],['Bat', 'b', 1, 3],['Bat', 'b', 1, 2],['Mat', 'm', 1, 1],['Fat', 'f', 1, 13]]

counts = Counter(word for word, *other_stuff in lineList)

filtered = [word for word, count in counts.items() if count >= 2]

for number, word in enumerate(filtered, start=1):
    print("{: >2}.".format(number), word)
```

prints

```
 1. Cat
 2. Bat
```

If you can't import `Counter` you can write a basic replacement pretty easily:

```
def Counter(seq):
    d = {}
    for item in seq:
        d[item] = d.get(item, 0) + 1
    return d
```

(`Counter` has more features, but this is all we're using)

You can then select a word with:

```
def choose(filtered):
    while True:
        choice = input("Select a word: ")
        try:
            choice = int(choice)
            return filtered[choice-1]
        except ValueError, IndexError:
            print("Please enter a number on the list")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right there, just check to see if the value of the second item in the nested list is greater than 1.

```
list1 = [['Cat', 2], ['Bat', 3], ['Fat', 1], ['Mat', 1]]

index = 1
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i][1] > 1:
        print (str(index)+ ". " + str(list1[i][0]))
        index += 1
```

This prints:

```
1. Cat
2. Bat
```

Comment: So, the value 'i' inside the if statement in the for loop is the index of your original lineList. Use that index number to get the info of the original list.

Comment: I answered in a different comment because the problem is now stated a bit differently

Answer (score 0):

You changed the description a bit so I rewrote the answer to be more fitting

```
lineList = [['Cat', 'c', 1, 'x'],['Cat', 'a', 2, 'x'],['Cat', 't', 3, 'x'],['Bat', 'b', 1, 3],['Bat', 'b', 1, 2],['Mat', 'm', 1, 1],['Fat', 'f', 1, 13]]


#First we create a dictionary with the repeating words in the list you gave
nameList = []    
frequencyDict = {}
for i in range(len(lineList)):

    if lineList[i][0] in frequencyDict.keys():
        frequencyDict[lineList[i][0]] += 1
    else:
        frequencyDict[lineList[i][0]] = 1

    #this will give you a list with the order
    #it will be useful to get the indices of the repeating word later
    nameList.append(lineList[i][0]) 


# Printing a list of values when if they are repeated
index = 1
repeats = []
for i in frequencyDict.keys():

    if frequencyDict[i] > 1: #This if statement checks if it was repeated or not

        print(str(index)+ ". " + i)
        repeats.append(i) # we also crete yet another list so the user can call it with his input later
        index += 1



x = (int(input("Which item on the list would you like to know more information about: \n")) -1) #note that we are subtracting one from the input so it matches the index of the list

# Here I am trying to get all the indices that start with the word that user replied
indicesList = []
for i in range(len(nameList)):
    if nameList[i] == repeats[x]:
        indicesList.append(i)

# Here I am printing the value that is in the index 1 and 2 of the nested list in Linelist
for i in range(len(indicesList)):
    print(str(lineList[indicesList[i]][1]) +
        " = " +
        str(lineList[indicesList[i]][2]))
```